# Where to use Image Magick with Pebble?

Tags: javascript, c, pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, pebble-js

I'm following [Pebble's tutorial](https://developer.getpebble.com/blog/2014/10/29/Displaying-remote-images/) to display remote images on a Pebble watch and it doesn't say where I'm supposed to put the Image Magick code that will convert the pngs. This is the code

```
convert myimage.png \
  -adaptive-resize '144x168>' \
  -fill '#FFFFFF00' -opaque none \
  -type Grayscale -colorspace Gray \
  -colors 2 -depth 1 \
  -define png:compression-level=9 -define png:compression-strategy=0 \
  -define png:exclude-chunk=all \
  myimage.pbl.png
```

Comment: This isn't code. It is a command line. You just run it from a shell/command prompt.

Comment: So I should save it as a shell script that runs whenever images are pulled?

Comment: You don't _have to_ put it into a script as you can run it directly from the shell command line. But if you are doing it often or as part of a series of steps then yes, you might want to put it into a shell script. Or you could put it into a php script. Or run it from cron. Or spawn it from C code. Or whatever your project requires.